# Fourier Transform of an exponential function with sine modulation

Tags: fourier-transform, matlab

I want to know the frequency domain spectrum of an exponential which is modulated with a sine function that is changing with time.

The time-domain form is,

$$ s(t) = e^{j \frac{4\pi}{\lambda} \mu \frac{\sin(\Omega t)}{\Omega}} $$

Here, $ \mu $, $  \Omega $  and $ \lambda $ are constants.

A quick implementation in MATLAB gives me the following in the frequency/velocity domain.

[image]

The code is given below.

clear;

```
close all;





lambda = 0.03;





mu = 4 * 2/lambda; % Mean Doppler frequency

Omega_rpm = 60; % in RPM

Omega = 2*pi/60 * Omega_rpm; % In rad/s

BW_deg = 1.8; % beam width in degree

BW = BW_deg * pi/180; % beam width in radian



v_amb = 7.5;





PRT = 1e-3;

f_amb = 1/(2 .* PRT);





p0 = 0*pi/180; % start angle

p1 = 360*pi/180; % end angle



N_BW = 1;  % Number of beam widths to integrate



M = round((p1 - p0)/(BW * N_BW)); % Number of azimuth points







hs = N_BW * round(BW/Omega/PRT); % hits per scan -> Sweeps in one beamwidth



N = hs * M; % Total number of points in the time axis



th = linspace(p0, p1, N); % All the angles





phi = linspace(th(1), th(end), M); % Angle of the sectors





t1 = 0:PRT:(N - 1)*PRT; % Time axis



ph_ = (2 * pi * mu .* t1);

s_ = (exp(1j .* ph_ .* (sin(eps + Omega .* t1)./(eps + Omega .* t1))));



vel_axis = linspace(-f_amb, f_amb, N); % frequency axis for the entire rotation



s_f = fftshift(fft(s_));

figure; plot(vel_axis*lambda/2, (abs(s_f)), 'LineWidth', 2); grid on;



xlabel('Doppler velocity [ms^{-1}]', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');

ylabel('Spectrum', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');

title('Spectrum function'); grid on;
```

I want to know what this function should look like in the spectrum domain analytically.

Comment: looks like Rob McElhenney's beard in Mythic Quest

Comment: @DavidP haha nice analogy!